# how can i get CURSOR using oracledb.BIND_OUT from oracle procedure in node.js?

Tags: node.js, cursor, node-oracledb

please help, how can i get CURSOR using oracledb.BIND_OUT from oracle procedure in node.js?

My Code:

```
DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin 
INSEL_TEMP('new name 1', cur);
end;
```

working in oracle
BUT
not working in NODE.JS

```
........    
    var _endCreation = function (result, error) {
    }
    var ora_binds = {
        name: 'insert new name',
        cur: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR }
    }
    _umodel.execute('BEGIN INSEL_TEMP(:name, :cur); END;'
    , ora_binds, { resultSet: true }, _endCreation);
........
```

Problem:

// when 'begin INSEL_TEMP(:name, :cur) end;' then result is undefined

// when 'select * from table;' then result with recordSet

// why? how can i get cursor handle when node.js oracle procedure calling ...

// help me please

Comment: DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin 
INSEL_TEMP('new name 1', cur);
end;    it is working..... but node.js cannot get cursor.. ???

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/refcursor.js Try removing the options object: {resultSet: true}

Comment: my procedure is

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE INSEL_TEMP (p_name IN NVARCHAR2, p_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
v_id NVARCHAR2(36);
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CMS_TEMP (NAME) VALUES (p_name) RETURNING ID INTO v_id;
COMMIT;
OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT * FROM CMS_TEMP WHERE ID=v_id;
END INSEL_TEMP;

Comment: {resultSet: true} removed!,  it is working thank you, @DanMcGhan